# How to get particular field value in sql table using time in where Condition?

Tags: sql

I need to get particular Shiftname using only current system time 
Table Name:tblShiftName

```
ID    ShiftName STime           ETime
1     S1        08:30:00        16:30:00
2     S2        16:31:00        00:30:00
3     S3        00:31:00        08:30:00
```

For example my input time in 17:11 Now the output is S2

The above is my expected result but i had'nt get that answer

What I have tried:

The following is mty query is only working for

```
SELECT ShiftName FROM tblShiftName WHERE '17:15' BETWEEN STime AND ETime
```

DataType :-Stime -DateTime
           ETime -DateTime

Comment: which datatype are STime and ETime ???

Comment: `WHERE '17:15' BETWEEN STime AND ETime
   OR (ETime < STime  and '17:15' BETWEEN STime AND ETime + 1 day)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where (stime < etime and @input_time between stime and etime) or
      (stime > etime and @input_time not between etime and stime);
```

It is unclear what happens at the boundaries, so `between` may not be the right choice of logic.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=193cd43583b0b057b0e174689bd4a494) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: When i use this query 
 select t.*
from vwShiftDetail t
where (starttime < endtime and '03:34 AM' between starttime and endtime) or
      (starttime > endtime and '03:34 AM' not between starttime and endtime);

The result will be showed as below
ID             STime       ETime
2 16:31 00:30
3 00:31 08:30

Comment: But i need to get S3 answer only

Comment: @Flower . . . There was a typo in the answer.  Fixed now.

Comment: Its Working Sir

Comment: I've an another Doubt how to set Same Date  Between if Today's morning time  08:30 AM to Next Day Morning 08:30 AM

Comment: @Flower . . . This should address that issue.